# Connection between gas flow rate and diameter of tubing

Tags: pressure, flow

First time poster, long time troller and curious student. I have a bit of a conundrum that I would love some input on... Here's the problem.

I have an air flow system is under constant pressure of .44 psi or 3033.693 Pa, this system is a 4 foot long straight section of tubing which has an internal diameter of 0.79375 mm. I am having discrepancies in flow rate between two testing stations and I have a hunch that the internal diameters of the two are not identical as the flow rate from one is 50 ml/min and the other is 48 ml/min.

In trying to determine if this is the case (at STP), I have been looking at the Hagen - Poiseuille equation but I am not sure if there is a better means of approaching this or if I am misguided in my attempts of distinguishing if the internal diameter could be the issue between the two systems. Any help or guidance would be great!

Comment: *::dons pedantic professor hat::* You don't have five significant figures in diameter, much less seven in pressure. *::doffs headwear::* If you are talking about the flow rate proportional to $R^4$ law then that only applies to laminar flaw and ask yourself how big a change in diameter would be needed to account for a 4% difference in flow.

Comment: This is based off of information given to me, I apologize if sig figs are off, and I really appreciate the direction you've given me!